# Is there a sql query to find all errors in a Mirth channel?

Tags: javascript, sql, mirth

I'm curious as to if there is a way to find a total number of errors in a Mirth instance across the various channels

Answer (score 0):

You can run dump stats using the CLI utility of Mirth connect .Navigate to the installation folder of your server instance then type `mccommand -a https_address -u username -p password` to launch Mirth CLI. Next, type `dump stats "path to spit the txt file"`. The text file will have an errored column for error counts on all deployed channels

Answer (score 0):

It's not pretty but this worked for me:

```
declare @query nvarchar(max)
select @query = 'select sum(result.errorcount) from (' + stuff(
    (       
        select distinct ' union all select count([ID]) as errorcount from '
            + table_name +' where [status] = ''E'''
        from information_schema.columns
        where table_name like 'D_MM%'
        for xml path('')
    ), 1, 11, '') + ') as result'
exec(@query)
```